# Young, Exercise 2.11 -- Closed Subspace?

Tags: functional-analysis

Take $W[0,1]$ to be the space of continuously differentiable functions $[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ with inner product
$$ \langle f, g \rangle := \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\overline{g(x)} + f'(x)\overline{g'(x)} \ dx. $$
We're asked to show that $\langle f, \cosh \rangle = f(1) \cosh (1)$ and to deduce (presumably from that) that
$$ C := \lbrace f \in W[0,1] : f(1) = 0 \rbrace$$
is a closed subspace of $W[0,1]$.

The problem I'm having is showing closedness of $C$. So we have that $C$ is a subspace of $Span \lbrace \cosh \rbrace^{\perp}$. Cool, but I don't think this is that helpful. Let's say we take a sequence $(f_{k}) \subset C$ with $\| g - f_{k} \| \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ for some $g \in W[0,1]$. Perhaps using the fact that $\|g - f_{k} \| = \|f \| - \langle g, f_{k} \rangle - \langle f_{k}, g \rangle + \|g \|$ might help, somehow getting that $\langle g, f_{k} \rangle \to 0$.

I'd appreciate any small hints, but please don't make things too explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this wasn't so bad. We know that $f \mapsto \langle f, \cosh \rangle$ is a continuous map and $C$ is not just contained in the kernel of this map, but it *is* the kernel, and so $C$ is closed.